# Dual Cone Containment

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, dual-cone

I have the following conjecture which, as of now, I can neither prove nor disprove:

> Let $H$ be a hilbert space, and let $C \subset H$ be a closed [(convex) cone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_cone) with the property that $\overline{\operatorname{span}(C)} = H$.  Let $C^*$ denote the [dual cone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_cone#Dual_cone) to $C$.
>
> Then, either $C \subseteq C^*$, or $C^* \subseteq C$.

If this is well known, I would like a reference.  If it is not, then I'd like to prove or disprove it.  I would be very interested in results that apply to the finite dimensional case $H = \Bbb R^n$ (or $H = \Bbb C^n$), if such results are easier to obtain.

It is notable that the spanning property of $S$ is important.  In particular, if $S$ is a proper subspace, then $S^* = S^\perp$.

Any feedback here is appreciated.

---

A partial result that may be useful here:

> Let $C_0$ be a self-dual (convex) cone (that is, $C_0 = C_0^*$).  If $C$ is a closed convex cone with $C \subset C_0$ or $C_0 \subset C$, then $C$ satisfies the conjecture.

This is a fairly immediately consequence of the following property of dual cones:

> If $C \subset D$ are subsets of $H$, then $D^* \subset C^*$.

It would be sufficient, then, to show that any cone with the spanning property must be contained in or contain some self-dual cone.

Comment: As for how this came up: there are a lot of convex-cones that come up in the study of positive-maps and quantum entanglement, and all of these cones seem to have this property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your claim seems to be true in $\mathbb{R}^n$ for $n \in \{0,1,2\}$. In three dimensions one can construct counterexamples.

We define the vectors
\begin{equation*}
 a =
 \begin{pmatrix}
  1 \\ 0 \\ 0
 \end{pmatrix}
 ,\quad
 b =
 \begin{pmatrix}
  -1 \\ 1 \\ 0
 \end{pmatrix}
 ,\quad
 c =
 \begin{pmatrix}
  0 \\ 1 \\ 1
 \end{pmatrix}
 .
\end{equation*}
Then, these vectors span $\mathbb{R}^3$.
Now, let $C$ be the conic hull of these vectors. Since $b^\top a = -1$, $a$ and $b$ do not belong to $C^*$.
However, we have $d = (1, 2, -1)^\top \in C^* \setminus C$, since $a^\top d, b^\top d, c^\top d > 0$.

The key is that the cone $C$ is rather slim in one direction, but fat in a direction orthogonal to the slim direction.

An other counterexample should be the Lorentz cone
\begin{equation*}
 \{ (t, x) \in \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}^2 : \|x\|_A \le t \}
\end{equation*}
with $\|x\|_A^2 = x^\top A \, x$,
if the symmetric, positive definit matrix $A$ is carefully chosen (two different eigenvalues).

Finally, one can produce a whole zoo of counterexamples.
Assume the closed convex cones $C_1, C_2 \subset Y$ span $Y$ and $C_1 \subsetneq C_1^*$, $C_2^* \subsetneq C_2$.
Then, the cone $C = C_1 \times C_2$ spans $Y^2$, but neither $C \subset C^*$ nor $C^* \subset C$ hold.