# Subset relation between convex cone and its dual

Tags: convex-analysis, dual-cone

Let $C$ be a convex cone and $C^*$ its dual cone. It seems for me that either $C\subseteq C^*$ or $C^* \subseteq C$ at least in 2 dimension. Is it correct? if so, is it the case also for higher dimension?

I'm interested in the proof if it is true or a contradictory example if it is not.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is correct in two dimensions (if $\operatorname{span}(C)$ is dense)  and a proof should be not too hard. However, there are counterexamples in dimension $3$, see https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1482741/58577.

Comment: Thanks. I see your post. However, I have a problem with your example in 3D. Based on the definition (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_cone_and_polar_cone), $d \in C^*$  if $a^T d, b^T d, c^T d > 0$; while you mentioned the opposite (less than zero)!!

Comment: @littleO: I corrected my answer. Thank you.

Comment: @Mojtaba: Yes, you are right. I think $d = (1,2,-1)$ should do the job?

Comment: @gerw: Still doesn't work. This time $d \in C^*$ but also $d \in C$; since you can say $d=4a+3b-c$.

Comment: @Mojtaba: No, $C$ consists only of **non-negative** linear combinations of $a$, $b$, $c$.

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Answer (score 0):

One good example of a convex cone to keep in mind is a subspace $C$ of $\mathbb R^n$.  In this case, the dual cone $C^*$ is the orthogonal complement of $C$.  So there is no inclusion either way in this example.

Here's a proof that if $C$ is a subspace of $\mathbb R^n$ then $C^* = C^\perp$ (the orthogonal complement of $C$).  First of all, clearly $C^\perp \subset C^*$.  So we only need to show that $C^* \subset C^\perp$.  Let $x \in C^*$.  If $y \in C$, then $\langle x , y \rangle \geq 0$
and also $\langle x , -y \rangle \geq 0$.  Thus $\langle x, y \rangle = 0$.  This shows that $x$ is orthogonal to every vector in $C$.  In other words, $x \in C^\perp$.  So, we can conclude that $C^* \subset C^\perp$.

Comment: I think in your example for 2 dimension, based on the definition, $C^∗$ is the positive half-space created by the orthogonal complement of $C$, which contains $C$. So, containment still holds.

Comment: @Mojtaba No, if $C$ is a subspace, then $C^*$ is the orthogonal complement of $C$; I added a proof of this fact.